# Replace \n", with ",

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have data in a file in this format as given below

```
"253539","","Company1 Name  
","0","1"
"255229","","Ramu ","0","1"
"253548","","Mater Name/Id 
","0","1"
"255229","","Ram Lakh","0","1"
"253619","","CHild Name/Ids 
","0","1"
```

Every line has \n appended to it.

How can I replace \n", to ", in shell script to get the output as

```
"253539","","Company1 Name/Id  ","0","1"
"255229","","Ramu ","0","1"
"253548","","Mater Name/Id ","0","1"
"255229","","Ram Lakh","0","1"
"253619","","CHild Name/Id ","0","1"
```

Need to automate a process so have to write in shell script.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk '/"$/ {print a$0; a=""; next} {a=$0}' file
"253539","","Company1 Name  ","0","1"
"255229","","Ramu ","0","1"
"253548","","Mater Name/Id ","0","1"
"255229","","Ram Lakh","0","1"
"253619","","CHild Name/Ids ","0","1"
```

What it does is to store in `a` the line in case it does not end with `"`. If it does, it prints the stored line plus the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about doing this easily in shell, but I made a throw-away Perl script to do it:

```
perl -e 'foreach (<>) { chop; print; print "\n" if /"$/ }' < mydata.csv
```

It works by outputting a newline only if the line ends in `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
 [[ $line =~ '"'$ ]] && echo "$line" || echo -n "$line"
done < file
```

e.g. on your input file

```
> ./abovescript
"253539","","Company1 Name","0","1"
"255229","","Ramu ","0","1"
"253548","","Mater Name/Id","0","1"
"255229","","Ram Lakh","0","1"
"253619","","CHild Name/Ids","0","1"
```

Answer (score 0):

if @fedorqui's answer can be accepted, then here is the shorter code.

```
awk '{printf $0 (/"$/?RS:X)}' file
```